# pandas fill dates + multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

let's say i have the following data

```
date          id1       id2     category    value
01/01/2019    1000      2000    income      1.0
01/01/2019    1000      2010    income      1.0
01/01/2019    1000      2000    expense     1.0
01/01/2019    1000      2010    expense     1.0
01/02/2019    1000      2000    income      2.0
01/02/2019    1000      2010    income      2.0
01/02/2019    1000      2000    expense     2.0
01/02/2019    1000      2010    expense     2.0
01/04/2019    1000      2000    income      3.0
01/04/2019    1000      2010    income      3.0
01/04/2019    1000      2000    expense     3.0
01/04/2019    1000      2010    expense     3.0
```

I would like to fill in the missing date 01/03/2019, but also a row for each combination of id1, id2 and category.  so in my case, 4 rows would be added:

```
date          id1       id2     category    value
01/03/2019    1000      2000    income      2.0
01/03/2019    1000      2010    income      2.0
01/03/2019    1000      2000    expense     2.0
01/03/2019    1000      2010    expense     2.0
```

I am familiar with back filling and forward filling dates when that is the the only index, but the above particular problem of backfilling by the combination of values from multiple columns is giving me trouble.  Any thoughts of an easy way to do this using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a pivot problem 1st , then become a `resample` and `ffill` problem

```
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['key']=df.groupby('date').cumcount()

newdf=df.set_index(['date','key']).unstack().resample('D').mean().ffill().stack().reset_index(level=0)

newdf

          date     id1     id2  value
key                                  
0   2019-01-01  1000.0  2000.0    1.0
1   2019-01-01  1000.0  2010.0    1.0
2   2019-01-01  1000.0  2000.0    1.0
3   2019-01-01  1000.0  2010.0    1.0
0   2019-01-02  1000.0  2000.0    2.0
1   2019-01-02  1000.0  2010.0    2.0
2   2019-01-02  1000.0  2000.0    2.0
3   2019-01-02  1000.0  2010.0    2.0
0   2019-01-03  1000.0  2000.0    2.0
1   2019-01-03  1000.0  2010.0    2.0
2   2019-01-03  1000.0  2000.0    2.0
3   2019-01-03  1000.0  2010.0    2.0
0   2019-01-04  1000.0  2000.0    3.0
1   2019-01-04  1000.0  2010.0    3.0
2   2019-01-04  1000.0  2000.0    3.0
3   2019-01-04  1000.0  2010.0    3.0
```

Comment: this works, except if there are columns what string values.   i think the mean() function will cause those to get dropped.  any suggestions for those?

Comment: @user3693559 change mean() to first()